# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: =

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I created a new maven project in Eclipse and on runtime I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: =
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: =
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: =. Program will exit.
```

In other threads the class is mentioned where the problem occurs but here it simply says nothing. 
The code is also used in a different project (with slight tweaks in terms of calling a method) but the rest of it is same. 
If anyone can help me resolve this issue..it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like *something* is passing in `=` as the class name. It doesn't say nothing - it says `=`.

For example, when I run:

```
java =
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class =
```

There's no colon, but it's otherwise the same.

Look at where you're *trying* to specify the class name, and see whether there's a stray `=` around. For example, suppose you had:

```
java -Dfoo = bar ClassName
```

instead of

```
java -Dfoo=bar ClassName
```

You'd see the same thing. I'm not familiar with Maven, but if you ever specify a set of arguments in it, I'd look at that part of the configuration file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990292/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-jboss-util-nested same issue but not solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Deleting the workspace** worked for me.