# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/Nested RuntimeException

Tags: java, jboss, noclassdeffounderror, jboss5.x

When I start my jBoss5.x server I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/Nested
RuntimeException
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.doInit(AbstractServerImpl.java
:190)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.init(AbstractServerImpl.java:1
73)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.init(AbstractServerImpl.java:1
43)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:218)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.util.NestedRuntimeExcepti
on
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

I have set my java class path
I am fresher with jBoss so I cant understand the reason for the issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: How have you configured your Classpath?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, twiddle script throws the same exception. After some struggle I found that jbossall-client.jar was missing. I copied it under client folder and it worked as expected.